# Do we omit "the" and use "that/those" when referring specific events?

Tags: articles, usage, determiners

Suppose today is Wednesday. I saw 3 concerts consecutively in 3 days in the past with the detail is as follows: I saw the first concert on Sunday, the second was on Monday, and the last concert I saw was on Tuesday. (In total, I saw 3 concerts).

In the present (Wednesday), I tell someone about how I feel that I saw 3 concerts recently. I'm confused as to which one I should use between these two:

1. I liked **the** concerts.
2. I liked **those** concerts.

Let's say I don't usually like concerts in general, but I liked **the**/**those** 3 concerts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are possible.

If you say *those* you are explicitly "pointing to" (not necessarily literally) the particular concerts.

If you say *the concerts* you are assuming that the hearer knows which concerts you mean: if you've already talked about them, the hearer will know, and it will make sense.

So if your last example is the beginning of a conversation, you almost certainly want to say *those*. But if your friend knew you were at them, you can probably get your meaning across with *the*.